# htaccess not removing URL parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to remove Trailing Slash from all our URLs of type .html
I am using the following code

```
RewriteRule (.+?)\.html.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/t4/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

This code works very close to what we need. We get issue with this code when we try to redirect a URL like

```
/a.html/b.php?c=1
```

This URL is redirected to

```
/a.html?c=1
```

I do not know why this happens. I would like this url to be /a.html
looks like the URL parameter is retained. Can you help on this get even the URL parameters removed while redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `?` to the end of your rule's target:

```
RewriteRule (.+?)\.html.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/t4/$1.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: A **?** at the very end of the target (replacement URL/URI) should suppress any original Query String. Adding your own Query String to the target will suppress the original QS. If you want to define your own QS, yet keep the original too, use the `[QSA]` flag (Query String Append).

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?\.html).+?[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
```